# Name doesn't exist in the current context LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing a left outer join on multiple tables. I am getting the following error `"The name 'ep' does not exist in the current context"`

Getting this error on 2 nd join onwards. What am I doing wrong.

```
from c in Corporates

join ep in EmployeePositions on c.Id equals ep.CorporateId into eps

from epsj in eps.DefaultIfEmpty()

join e in Employees on ep.EmployeeId equals e.Id into es

from esj in es.DefaultIfEmpty()

join ee in EmployeeEvaluations on e.Id equals ee.EmployeeId into eels

from eelsj in eels.DefaultIfEmpty()

join ees in EmployeeEvaluationStatuses on ee.EvaluationStatusId equals ees.Id into eevls

from eevlsj in eevls.DefaultIfEmpty()

join v in Vouchers on e.Id equals v.EmployeeId into vs

from vsj in vs.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new { ep = ep, empEvals = ee, empEvalStatus = ees }
```

Comment: You changed the name of the variable from `ep` to `epsj` and similarly with the other variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an outer join (a `GroupJoin`, actually), the *range variable* changes. Let me explain. In your example, the first part ...

```
from c in Corporates
join ep in EmployeePositions on c.Id equals ep.CorporateId
```

... would be an inner join. The range variable is `ep` here. That's the variable you can use later on in the query.

Now you turn it into an outer join:

```
from c in Corporates
join ep in EmployeePositions on c.Id equals ep.CorporateId into eps
from epsj in eps.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The range variable now is `epsj`. So you should use `epsj` in the rest of the LINQ statement.

If you want, you can even reuse the range variable name:

```
from c in Corporates
join ep in EmployeePositions on c.Id equals ep.CorporateId into eps
from ep in eps.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: I always use the last approach (reusing the range variable name). This way the rest of the query is (almost) unaffected of the type of the join (`inner` and `left outer`). Almost because of course `left outer join` may need some `null` checks.